# Twig render other controller from base view

Tags: php, twig

I am using twig seperately, not from within Symfony.

I have base layout base.html. Other layouts extend that one and that seems to work fine.

If I have a controlleraction BlogPosts which passes an array of blogposts, I render the blog layout, which extend from the base layout to see that content. That works as intended

Now, I would like to pass variables to the base template, so it is visible on every page. How can I do this?

I found [this article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html), but that mentions it for symfony. On its own, twig does not have the render function.

Comment: Yuk. That's bad practice. The controllers should have finished their job, collected the view variables, and sent them up to the view for rendering. Jumping back out of Twig and into another controller action seems like a very bad idea. Why are you doing it like that?

Comment: Consider adding a public method in your `BlogPosts` and either add the result of the method as a global variable in `twig` or write a custom `twig function` which is capable of calling that public method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using twig without symfony, I assume your project directory structure is similar like this:

```
project
  - templates
     - base.html.twig
     - index.html.twig
  - vendor
  - index.php
```

So, your index.php code should be like:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates', getcwd());
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array('name' => 'Hello'));
```

So, if you want pass some variable to your base template, twig has method to add value for using globally

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates', getcwd());
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('title', 'HomePage');

echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array('name' => 'Hello'));
```

I hope this help